# What is the proper way to send a message to a particular client in a server-client structure?

Tags: java, tcp, client-server, master-slave

I am building this program where a server sends different order to different clients. One part of the program sends the order to the server, the server processes to which client the message goes to and then it sends it to the particular client it should go.

Here is the code where the message is send:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    boolean active = true;
    String oldMsgToDron = "";
    String to_print = "";
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
    while(active) {
        try {
            //msgToDron is declared in DronController as: public static volatile String msgToDron;
            to_print = DronController.msgToDron;

            if(to_print.equals(oldMsgToDron) == false) {
                
                System.out.println("Message we are sending to the dron: " + to_print);
                
                if(to_print.length()>45 && to_print.startsWith("!whisper") && dronId.equals(to_print.substring(9, 45))) {
                    bw.write("Server whispers:" + to_print.replace("!whisper " + dronId, ""));
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.flush();
                    System.out.println("Message we sent to the dron: " + to_print);
                }
                
                else if (to_print.startsWith("!whisper") == false){
                    bw.write(to_print);
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.flush();
                    System.out.println("A message for all drones has been sent.");
                }
                try{Thread.sleep(5);}catch(InterruptedException ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
                oldMsgToDron = "";
                to_print = "";
                DronController.msgToDronEsclavo = "";
            }

        }catch(IOException e) {
            try {
                active = false;
                if(bw != null) 
                    bw.close();
            }catch(IOException f) {e.printStackTrace();f.printStackTrace();break;}
        }           
    }
}
```

My problem is that the message is processed inside the thread that controls the connection to the client and at the end of the loop the message is changed to an empty string. This is so I can send the same order twice in a row and the server isn't constantly sending the same messages to the client.

The thing is that by doing it this way if I have 3 or more connections it starts to give me problems because whenever one of the threads reaches the end they turn the variables `DronController.msgToDronEsclavo`, `to_print` and `oldMsgToDron` to empty strings before the other threads had time to check if the message was for the client they have assigned.

How can I avoid that the different threads change the variable before the others have finished? Are there any kind of design pattern for this kind of structures? What are some good practices with this type of programs?

Also, I've thought about making the client check if the message sent is for them or not but I find this solution unsecure.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is the client who connects to the server via network - to request data or to send data. The server has no reliable way to know when the client would connect the next time, or trigger a connection itself.

If you want to send data from the server to the client there used to be patterns that the client would poll for data, or have always one request waiting for the next packet from the server. You may want to read about [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) and [Websocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)

Another pattern would be to install a [webhook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook), which essentially gives the server a URL at which the client can be reached. This in essence swaps the server to acting as client and the client to acting as server for this data transfer.

Well, the above was written related to your question title. Now looking at the content, you are asking how to prevent that threads impact each other.

Learn Java's concepts on thread synchronization. Here is a [nice tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The clients are listening to the server. They are drones that before the server sends any order to them they have already stablished a connection.

Also, all the connections are via tcp so I am not using any website to connect to the server, it is simply a computer I have waiting for connections.

Comment: A computer waiting for connections is usually called a server.